When I say "ring" what should the listener understand?
Does the word "ring" implicitly means a circular shape?

Ring doesn’t only means a circular shape, but have other meanings. Please see a dictionary.

@user1176409 the dictionary says it's only a circular shape.

Ring can be a verb too.

I meant what shape should form in the listener's head when I say ring. Would he ask me afterwards what shape is it?

Why do you doubt what the dictionary says?

I just wanna make sure it is the only meaning out there

Welcome! Questions that can be answered by a dictionary aren't covered here. If you have questions about something in a dictionary that confuses you, those are covered, but please make sure you explain what you found. I find around 36 meanings for "ring" in Merriam-Webster.

As you have found, the word ring implies a circular shape.  But, depending on the listener's experiences they may infer other properties.  To me, it implies a hole in the middle.  That is, not a disc, but more like a torus.

Thanks for contributing! But please don't answer questions that are off-topic or unclear; give the user a chance to improve them (though I don't know that there's an on-topic version of this one).
